# Program to an interface and the Observer Pattern

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

*First, a small introduction, to help you understand where I'm coming from*: I was not sure how to title this question, either like it is, or as *Repository tracking changes of the Unit of Work*.

I have two interfaces, `ChangeListener` and `ChangeSubject`, which are coupled:

```
interface ChangeListener
{
    public function onSubjectChanged(ChangeSubject $subject, array $data);
}
interface ChangeSubject
{
    public function addChangeListener(ChangeListener $listener);
}
```

and I also have a repository and a unit of work (WIP, I'll leave out some parts):

```
interface UnitOfWork extends ChangeSubject
{
    public function commit();
    public function hydrateChange(array $data, ArrayService $arrayService);
}

interface Repository extends ChangeListener
{
    public function commit() : \bool;
    public function commitCount() : \int;
}
```

Now, in my implementation of the `UnitOfWork`, let's call it `Book`, more precisely in the method `hydrateChange`, I notify the repository of the change, which is easy:

```
$repository->onSubjectChanged($this, $newHydration);
```

The problem is now that, within the repository, I need to know the book's id. But the repository's handling method receives a `ChangeSubject`, which does not have an id (which the `Book` has).

How to properly design such a system?

If PHP had generics, it would have been possible. A hacky solution, which I don't like, is using `instanceof`.

[image]

Comment: In this scenario you will end up using `instanceof` somewhere.
Why did you couple UnitOfWork with your Business Objects? The Business Objects should not be aware of persistence related issues.

Comment: @SebastianKeßler Where do you see a dependency between Business Objects and persistence? It's dependency inversion, the persistence gets injected as a ChangeListener from the outside, but there may be others too, like a security service which tracks who does what (accounting in security terms).

`instanceof` would not be necessary if PHP would support generics.

Comment: Hard to understand what this has to do with DDD...

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev The question is also tagged `design patterns` and `oop`. I've tagged it `ddd` because the classes involved are also a UOW and a Repository. Which means that people doing DDD in PHP are likely to have encountered this situation. Of course, DDD is more than just what is illustrated in this situation, it's the ubiquitous language, it's the bounded context, and so on.

Comment: You have misunderstood what unit of work is. A UoW is a group of changes where everything or nothing should be stored. In the DB world it could be represented by an transaction. http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html

Comment: @jgauffin Please provide a class diagram of how you would model this situation (including the UoW, the repository, and what else you see fit to make it work in practice in PHP), and I will gladly accept your elaborate answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: It was more then 10 years ago that I coded PHP. So any PHP specific answer would suck.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood a few of the concepts. If you get the following right, you should get back on track:

- **Don't implement unit of work in your domain objects.** The unit of work is just a technical helper that keeps track of changes. So the unit of work references the business object, e.g. to note "the book with ID 32 changed", but it isn't the same as a business object.
- **Make concrete repositories for your aggregate types.** A `BookRepository` should contain methods like `GetById(BookId)`, `GetByAuthor(Author)` and the like. Note: In languages with generics there may be an opportunity to extract generic parts, but in PHP, it's best to work on the concrete aggregate types like `Book`.

I suggest you learn more about the unit of work and repository patterns. Make sure you fully understand them before you try to use them. Also make sure you understand the different repository variations (e.g. command style repository vs collection style repository) to make an informed decision for your project.

Comment: Yeah, regarding your first bullet point: indeed I've mixed them. Regarding the second one: Yes, I do have those methods in the book repository.

For me,it's quite important to track exactly which fields of which book has been modified,that's why I pass a list of operational transformations via the `hydrateChange` method.

Ok, so I'll split the business logic and the UoW,but I still need to track each change somehow.

How would you do this?Marking a book as "dirty" by id is not enough, I need to know precisely what has changed.

I could calculate the change retroactively, but that's suboptimal.

Comment: I'm not sure that calculating the changes when a Book is passed back to the repository for saving (often called snapshot comparison) is such a bad thing. That's what most ORMs support out of the box, and that's what most projects use. If you really want to know about changes when they happen, then you need *proxy-based change tracking* for your aggregates. This may be non-trivial to build yourself though, so you may want to look for an ORM that supports it out of the box.